# Concatenate two strings without using strcat

Tags: c, malloc, string-concatenation

I wrote a function to concatenate two strings (`s` = `"computer"`; `t` = `"keyboard"`), but my code only returns `"keyboard"`. Please point out the mistakes.

```
char *concat(char *s, char *t) {
    s = malloc((strlen(s) + strlen(t) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    char *p = s;
    while (*p != '\0') {
        ++p;
    }
    while (*t != '\0') {
        *p++ = *t++;
    }
    *p = '\0';
    return s;
}
```

I do not want to use `strcat()`. This is a test program from Stepik, so I cannot change anything in the `main` function.
**Here is the question: ***Write a function which receives two character pointers and returns a new character pointer representing their concatenation.*****

Comment: `s = malloc(...)` overwrites the pointer you were passed, so the input string is lost. Then, if you find a `'\0'` in the memory allocated, that is by chance.

Comment: `char *concat(const char *s, const char *t) { char *u = malloc(strlen(s) + strlen(t) + 1); if (u) sprintf(u, "%s%s", s, t); return u; }`

Comment: I hate the wording of the original question ("Here is the question: [...]").  It conflates the the values of the pointers with the values of the data they point to, and this is precisely one of the areas that causes trouble for C students.  Course materials that fail to establish and maintain a clear distinction between those concepts thereby disserve students who use them.

Comment: @pmg sprintf to concat two strings. Lovely.

Comment: I prefer your `memcpy()` option (upvoted BTW), thanks @P__J__

Comment: @pmg The code solved it. I need to look up sprintf. Thanks!

Comment: @LPJeev: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *myconcat(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    size_t len1,len2;
    char *result = malloc((len1 = strlen(s1)) + (len2 = strlen(s2)) + 1);

    if(result)
    {
        memcpy(result, s1, len1);
        memcpy(result + len1, s2, len2 + 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Yes, very good job of doing students' homework for them.  At least some commentary about what is wrong with the OP's code would be in order.

Answer (score 0):

You have s="computer" when passed into a function, and then on the very first line you reassign it with malloc, so "computer" is gone.
You can debug your program step by step, or just print the values to the console. This will help you to find the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track:

- you allocate the correct amount of memory,
- you copy the second string correctly,
- you set the null terminator correctly,
- you return the pointer to the allocated block.

Yet there are some issues:

- you overwrite the pointer to the first string with that returned by `malloc()`,
- you read from the allocated memory block instead of copying the first string: this has undefined behavior,
- (minor) the argument strings should be declared as `const char *` as you do not modify these strings.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *concat(const char *s, const char *t) {
    char *ret = malloc((strlen(s) + strlen(t) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    char *p = ret;
    while (*s != '\0') {
        *p++ = *s++;
    }
    while (*t != '\0') {
        *p++ = *t++;
    }
    *p = '\0';
    return ret;
}
```